# Finding the search button in craigslist website

Tags: html, ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I want to make some ruby `watir` and `watir-webdriver` code to search craigslist for rooms. The code needs to find the HTML element for the search button. In the html code, it has an id=searchbtn. When I treat this element as a link or button and make my code click it, I get an error that the object is not found. I am not sure how   to make my code find this button. Please help me.

url = `http://newyork.craigslist.org/search/roo`

```
<button type="submit" id="searchbtn">
<span class="searchicon"></span>
</button>
```

**Full code here -**

```
require 'watir'
require 'rubygems'
# installed watir-webdriver, but did not require it.

craigslist = "http://newyork.craigslist.org/"
section = "search/roo"
website_section = craigslist + section
search_word = "subway"
html_search_text_box_id = "query"
html_button_id = "searchbtn"
search_page_string = "all new york"

# Create browser.
browser = Watir::Browser.new

puts "connecting to craislist at #{website_section}..."
browser.goto website_section

# Maximize browser
# browser.send_keys :f11

# Type there the text in variable
puts "entering search word = #{search_word}..."
browser.text_field(:name, html_search_text_box_id).set search_word 

#Waiting for search button to appear
Watir::Wait.until { browser.text.include? search_page_string }

puts "clicking on the search button..."
browser.button(:name, html_button_id).click

if browser.text.include? search_page_string
  puts "Test Passed. Found the expected string: #{search_page_string}..."
else
  puts "Test Failed! Could not find the expected string: #{search_page_string}..."
end

puts "End of code..."
browser.close
```

Running the code on linux ubunut 14 with ruby 1.9.3 and RVM.
`~projectRoot > ruby craigslist.rb`

**Error -**

```
/home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.11/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:513:in `assert_exists': unable to locate element, using {:name=>"searchbtn", :tag_name=>"button"} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)
    from /home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.11/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:119:in `click'
    from craigslist.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. `"Please help me."` Don't plead for help, that's why we're here. The best way to get help is to write a well thought-out question. When asking for help with code, we need to SEE a minimal example of the code in question, that is enough to demonstrate the problem you are having getting it to work. Less than that makes it seem like you are asking us to write the code for you, which isn't how Stack Overflow works. I'd suggest editing your question and adding a working snippet of code showing what you're trying to do otherwise your question is incomplete.

Comment: @theTinMan - I added the full working code.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to locate based on `:name` rather than `:id`.  Try `browser.button(:id, html_button_id).click` instead of `browser.button(:name, html_button_id).click`

Comment: I'm not a Watir user, but did some digging, and I think you'll want to find the button by it's ID rather than by it's name.  The Craigslist button doesn't have a name.  "searchbtn" is the button's ID.  ...and @DanWagner stole my thunder!  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is on line 29:

`browser.button(:name, html_button_id).click`

When I look at the source HTML, I see:

`<button type="submit" id="searchbtn"><span class="searchicon"></span></button>`

Which means you'd want to identify that button by its `:id`, not `:name`. Try this and see if the search is correctly executed:

`browser.button(:id, html_button_id).click`

Comment: Damn...stupid mistake. Thanks.

Comment: No problem -- one of the nicest parts of `watir` (and `selenium`) is that you can play with a browser instance straight from `irb`. That makes hashing out ideas really quick and painless